# New to python, when i run this code with inputs >= it runs smoothly when i run it with input<= i get an error

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height_input = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))


height_input >= 120

if height_input >= 120:
  print("Congrats! You're allowed to go on ride.")
else: print("Sorry, you're not allowed on ride.")

if height_input >= 120:
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))

if payment <= 18:
  print("You must pay $7")
else: print("You must pay $12")
```

(If i put height anthing less then 120cm i get an error when i put the height 120+ the code runs smoothly) sorry in advance im new to coding

i am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    if payment <= 18:
NameError: name 'payment' is not defined
```

Comment: ```payment``` can be undefined since it is inside the ```if``` statement.

Comment: These kinds of mistakes are better solved by drawing a diagram for your program first. Ask yourself: Do you want the program to continue if `height < 120`? If not, how should you modify the code to reflect that?

Comment: `height_input >= 120` ..? in 3rd line

Comment: @YashMehta It's just redundant, but doesn't hurt.

Comment: @PEPSI You are getting the error because when you put a height less than 120 `payment` is not initialized.  Either define `payment` outside the if condition `if height_input >= 120:
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))` with `payment = 0` if you want to add payment only if the height is more or equal to 120.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not because of the `<=`, But it is Because, When you enter a value in `height_input` greater than 120 then the below is never execute.

```
if height_input <= 120: # >= to <=
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))
```

This means the program never asks you to enter the value of payment input. Since it never defines you got the `NameError`.

---

You can solve this problem by defining a `payment` variable.

Like this;

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height_input = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))
payment = None

height_input >= 120

if height_input >= 120:
  print("Congrats! You're allowed to go on ride.")
else: print("Sorry, you're not allowed on ride.")

if height_input >= 120:
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))
if payment is not None:
    if payment <= 18:
      print("You must pay $7")
    else: print("You must pay $12")
else: 
    print("Payment not entered")
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined variable "payment" inside "if"

So, when you enter height less than 120:

```
if height_input >= 120:
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))
```

It gives false. So, the line -

```
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))
```

Doesn't run.
After that when you ask your code about the variable it doesn't understand what are you talking about. Because it isn't even declared!

From the look of your code, I guess the q is: see if a persons height is enough to ride and if he is able to ride then ask for payment. In that case the code should be:

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height_input = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))


height_input >= 120

if height_input >= 120:
    print("Congrats! You're allowed to go on ride.")
    payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))
    if payment <= 18:
        print("You must pay $7")
    else: print("You must pay $12")

else: print("Sorry, you're not allowed on ride.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix the code is by checking the height_input variable in the if statement

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height_input = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))


if height_input >= 120:
  print("Congrats! You're allowed to go on ride.")
else: print("Sorry, you're not allowed on ride.")

if height_input >= 120:
 payment = int(input("How old are you? "))

if height_input >= 120 and payment <= 18:
  print("You must pay $7")
elif height_input >= 120: print("You must pay $12")
```

If height_input is less than 120, Python will automatically exit the if statement without evaluating the second comparison.

I also cleaned up your code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to -

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height_input = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))


height_input >= 120

if height_input >= 120:
    print("Congrats! You're allowed to go on ride.")
    payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))
    if payment <= 18:
        print("You must pay $7")
    else:
        print("You must pay $12")
else: 
    print("Sorry, you're not allowed on ride.")
```

the problems were that

1. you repeated an if statement to print whether the person can ride and to ask for age. you should put both the actions in one if statement
2. many times one-line else statements give errors
3. you were supposed to put the age checking if/else statement in the height_input one because this way it would only ask for age if the height was enough. In your original code if the height would be less than 120 cm then the payment variable would not be created and you would get an error when you would try to compare payment variable with 18. so I put the payment if/else statement  in the height one so that the payment comparison would only exist if the payment variable itself existed.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my opnion, the most important thing is that you wanted to exit the program when height_input <= 120 but you forget to do it in the code. So here's my solution:

```py
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height_input = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))

if height_input >= 120:
  print("Congrats! You're allowed to go on ride.")
else:
  print("Sorry, you're not allowed on ride.")
  exit(0)

if height_input >= 120:
 payment = (int(input("How old are you? ")))

if payment <= 18:
  print("You must pay $7")
else: print("You must pay $12")
```

(And I deleted line 3 in your origin code for it has no meaning)